# Как оформить "если что" с тире позади?

Tags: пунктуация

> Он человек вспыльчивый и если что – кидает телефон в стену.

Comment: Т. е. перед если что?

Comment: Не удаётся редактировать коммент... *Он человек вспыльчивый и кидает телефон в стену, если что.*  Возможны варианты со знаками. *Он человек вспыльчивый и, если что, кидает телефон в стену; Он человек вспыльчивый и, если что, – кидает телефон в стену; Он человек вспыльчивый – и, если что, кидает телефон в стену.*

Comment: Ну так вы можете выбрать два варианта: Он человек вспыльчивый и, если что, кидает телефон в стенку. : Он человек вспыльчивый и, если что, --кидает телефон в стенку. Тире здесь дополнительный знак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Словарь многих выражений:
**если что** (ежели что) — если что случится, произойдет что-либо.

Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка:
[**если что**](https://phraseology.academic.ru/4013/%D0%95%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE) — ***разг.*** В необходимом случае. *Ребятам так нужны беседы по душам с другом, который много старше, мудрее, который сможет удержать, **если что,** добрым советом, натолкнуть на раздумье* (А. Кузнецова. Земной поклон).

Я бы написала это предложение так:
**Он человек вспыльчивый — если что, кидает телефон в стену.**

Дополнение (после комментария)

Мне *показалось*, что без **и** предложение выглядит "полегче".
С союзом так: **Он человек вспыльчивый — и, если что, кидает телефон в стену.**
Короткое "если что" и так требует паузы, поэтому мне думается, что тире лучше поставить *перед* выражением.

Comment: А союз куда делся? С ним-то как?

Comment: Изобразила дополнение в ответе — в комментарий бы всё "не влезло".

Comment: Спасибо, Римулик. Буду думу думати.

Answer (score 2):

**Он человек вспыльчивый, и если что —  кидает телефон в стену.**

Предложение сложное, поэтому ставится запятая перед И.

Перед ЕСЛИ не ставим запятую, имеется в виду составной союз ЕСЛИ...ТО.

Но так как местоимение ТО пропущено, то ставим тире на месте пропуска.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (с учетом замечаний и других ответов)

Фразеология — это, конечно, хорошо (можно пользоваться готовыми правилами). Только вот пользоваться надо правильно, с учетом семантики.

(1) Он человек вспыльчивый — если что, кидает телефон в стену.

Это **характеристика нервной системы персонажа** через его поведение. БСП, вторая часть раскрывает содержание первой.

(2) Он человек вспыльчивый, и если что –  кидает телефон в стену.

Это информация о том, **что может произойти с телефоном** у вспыльчивого хозяина. Здесь нужен союз И, обозначающий последовательность действий.

А теперь о самом выражении ***если что***. Оно довольно многозначно: если что произойдет (случится), если что будет нужно и т.д.   Поэтому можно восстановить его структуру в каждом случае.

Восстановили: **Он человек вспыльчивый, и если что не так, то кидает телефон в стену.**

А теперь сократим предложении, но на месте пропущенных слов поставим тире (в устной речи сделаем паузу).

Comment: Sharon, если честно, мне вообще не понятна функция тире перед если что. А вот по поводу запятой не согласен. Тире здесь стоит не потому, что пропущено вторая часть союза, а потому, что подразумевается резкое противопоставлние.

Comment: Серж, я объяснила тему в комментарии. Сначала нужно правильно понять смысл (а для этого нужен контекст), а потом подбирать подходящую грамматику и ставить запятые.

Comment: И все же запятую поставил бы. Вторая часть пропущена.  В правилах такое не оговаривается.

Comment: Серж, напишите Ваш вариант предложения, не могу понять, где нужна запятая.

Comment: Он человек вспыльчивый и, если что, --кидает телефон в стенку. Тире здесь дополнительный знак.

Comment: ЕСЛИ ЧТО напоминает вводное слово (иногда оно может быть наречием и вообще не обособляется). В середине предложения обособляется запятыми, может соединяться с присоединительными союзами. Может обособляться тире, но тире заменяет запятую, это не дополнительный знак.  Однородных сказуемых я здесь не вижу, это сложное предложение.. Примеры: А бесполезно… дорога узкая, кренделями, и если что ― машина валит любую ограду. [Дина Рубина. Медная шкатулка (сборник) (2015)]. О вас помнят, и если что ― в беде не оставят. [Михаил Елизаров. Библиотекарь (2007)]

Comment: В общем, правила для этого выражения еще не придумали, можно знаки препинания по интонации ставить. Хотя можно ориентироваться на выражение В СЛУЧАЕ ЧЕГО, они похожи.http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_123